# How to Integrate Chatbot features with Microsoft teams custom tabs

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a chatbot build on microsoft bot framework and deployed as an app on teams.
Is it possible to integrate custom tabs for the Chatbot App in  microsoft teams with inbuild functionality of the bot?

What i mean is if i provide custom tabs for my chatbot in teams through the manifest file. Would the user be able to click on any of the custom tab and invoke a respective intent of the chatbot? or OnEvent activity handler?
From what i have read on custom tabs is ,its used to render webpages through iframe. Has any anyone ever worked on this?

Comment: ,do you mean you have one custom tab and on onclick of custom tab you want the user to be redirected to the chatbot to some particular conversation?

Comment: Sort of.. on click of the tab.. is it possible to invoke a different function within the webservice. Or is it just used to render web pages?

Comment: If not could the custom tabs be used to make an api call?.. to custom api within my service.

Comment: Tab can be used to make API calls. Could you please go through [tab authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-silent-aad)? Here to authenticate tab we will use graph API. Also could you please go through the sample [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node/blob/master/src/views/tab/simple/simple.hbs#L131)?